Unable to execute a single test case using xcodebuild -only-testing option
We have a test suite which has nearly 1000 test cases. We need to run the test suite on a machine that is different than the build machine. We resigned the app and the test ipas, installed it on the device and are now trying to execute a single test case using the -only-testing option. Below is the command:
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun MultipleTestCases.xctestrun -destination 'platform=iOS,id=00008101-00192C293ED0001E' -only-testing:myapp-ios-mobileUITests/SearchTests/testBrowseSheetIsDisplayedWhenMoreResultsItemIsTapped_SEARCH35

However, no tests excuted. It says 0 tests passed, 0 tests failed.
We tried skip-testing and that seems to be working so not sure why only-testing is not. I dont have access to source code of app or test.
Any help appreciated!!!
